# The invertibility of matrix $(I - XX')$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

$I$ is an identity matrix of size $n \times n$. $X$ is a matrix of size $n \times k$(Assuming $k \leq n$).

As we know, $(I+XX')$ is invertible. Because $(I+XX') = (I(blank)X)*(I(blank)X)'$, where $(I  (blank)X)$ has full rank of n.

So I'm wondering whether $(I-XX')$ has a similar property? What's the invertibility of matrix $(I - XX')$?

Comment: What do you mean by "blank" here?

Comment: Block matrix[I  X],size n\*(n+k).

Comment: How can a rectangular matrix be invertible?

Comment: Oh!yes...I think made a mistake. Thanks for pointing out, Behaviour!

Comment: @Damon: to see $I+XX'$ is invertible, one way is first note that $XX'$ is positive semidefinite so has nonnegative eigenvalues. Adding $1$ to each of these eigenvalues gives us the eigenvalues of $I+XX'$. Thus, the latter has strictly positive eigenvalues and is therefore invertible.

Answer (score 2):

$I-XX'$ need not be invertible. For example, take $X=I$.

More generally, take a matrix $P$ such that $PP'=I$.

To fully answer your question, note that $XX'$ is a real symmetric matrix, and can be diagonalized. So, $I-XX'$ is not invertible precisely when there exists at least one eigenvalue of $XX'$ equal to $1$.

Comment: Yes..that's a good example! So what if X is not equal to I?

Comment: @Damon: Still not true- take a matrix $P$ with $PP'=I$

Comment: if k < n, how can you find a matrix P with PP′=I ? I don't think it exists.

Comment: @Damon: yes. But if $k=n$ there exists many such examples. Anyway, I will edit and add the most general "answer" as a hint and leave this thread.